# Fetching multiple records from MySQL in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am trying to fetch multiple records from MySQL database using Hibernate Query Language. After several failed attempts using **query.find()** and **query.list()**, I figured out that the problem lies in my query. But I am not sure whats wrong with my query. The following is the code for fetching the records:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<Paper> getPapersByCondition() { 

//      Query q = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession().createQuery("select paperID, paperTitle, abstractOfThePaper, status from Paper where reviewerID is null");       
//      List<Paper> list = null;
//      for(Object o : q.list()) {
//          System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
//          list.add((Paper)o);
//          System.out.println(((Paper)o).getPaperTitle());
//      }
//      System.out.println("#################");
//      System.out.println(list.size());
    //return list;



    List<Object> o = getHibernateTemplate().find("select paperID, paperTitle from Paper where reviewerID is null");
    List<Paper> list = null;
    for(Object one : o) {
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
        list.add((Paper)one);
        System.out.println(((Paper)one).getPaperTitle());
    }
    System.out.println("#################");
    System.out.println(list.size());
    return list;
}
```

The only output that gets printed in my console (using both methods `query.list()` and `query.find()` )out of the above code is :

```
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
```

I have only one record in the table while running the above code. ***The fields reviewerfeedback and reviewerid are null.***

The table papers (maps to POJO Class: Paper) has following fields:

**paperid             (int),
papertitle          (varchar),
paperdatafile       (blob),
abstractofthepaper  (varchar),
status              (varchar),
reviwerfeedback     (varchar),
reviewerid          (varchar)**

Please help me out in resolving the above problem.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
My POJO Paper Class:

```
package com.GDP.test.model;

import java.sql.Blob;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "papers")
public class Paper {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "paperid")
private int paperID;

@Column(name = "papertitle")
private String paperTitle;

@Column(name = "paperdatafile")
private Blob paperDataFile;

@Column(name = "abstractofthepaper")
private String abstractOfThePaper;  

@Column(name = "status")
private String status;

@Column(name = "paperdownloadname")
private String paperDownloadName;

@Column(name = "reviewerfeedback")
private String reviewerFeedback;

@Column(name = "reviewerid")
private String reviewerID;

public Paper(String paperTitle, Blob paperDataFile, String abstractOfThePaper, String status,
        String paperDownloadName) {
    super();
    this.paperTitle = paperTitle;
    this.paperDataFile = paperDataFile;
    this.abstractOfThePaper = abstractOfThePaper;
    this.status = status;
    this.paperDownloadName = paperDownloadName;
}



public Paper() {
    super();
}

public int getPaperID() {
    return paperID;
}

public void setPaperID(int paperID) {
    this.paperID = paperID;
}

public String getPaperTitle() {
    return paperTitle;
}

public void setPaperTitle(String paperTitle) {
    this.paperTitle = paperTitle;
}

public Blob getPaperDataFile() {
    return paperDataFile;
}

public void setPaperDataFile(Blob paperDataFile) {
    this.paperDataFile = paperDataFile;
}

public String getAbstractOfThePaper() {
    return abstractOfThePaper;
}

public void setAbstractOfThePaper(String abstractOfThePaper) {
    this.abstractOfThePaper = abstractOfThePaper;
}


public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getPaperDownloadName() {
    return paperDownloadName;
}

public void setPaperDownloadName(String paperDownloadName) {
    this.paperDownloadName = paperDownloadName;
}

public String getReviewerFeedback() {
    return reviewerFeedback;
}

public void setReviewerFeedback(String reviewerFeedback) {
    this.reviewerFeedback = reviewerFeedback;
}

public String getReviewerID() {
    return reviewerID;
}

public void setReviewerID(String reviewerID) {
    this.reviewerID = reviewerID;
}
```

}

This is the error I get in my Chrome browser while executing the corresponding front end code to display the fetched records:
       ***org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: 
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.GDP.test.model.Paper***

***java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.GDP.test.model.Paper***

Comment: Please add the code for the related entity classes. Did you try saving a `Paper` entity object to the table using hibernate?

Comment: please add entity classes.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Added my entity class. Yes I already tried to insert a record to the table. There is only one record in the table while running the above code. The fields reviewerfeedback and reviewerid are null in the table.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the line

```
list.add((Paper)one);
```

`one` is not `Paper` cause of you do `select paperID, paperTitle`. It is an array `[paperID, paperTitle]`.
You need to do something like this

```
List<Paper> papers = (List<Paper>)getHibernateTemplate().find("from Paper where reviewerID is null");
```

Comment: Here I am trying to fetch only paperID, paperTitle fields from the table. Besides if I try the foll. way: List<Object[]> o = getHibernateTemplate().find("select paperID, paperTitle from Paper p where reviewerID is null");, I get an error like: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<Object[])